# Faster approach than find_in_set in MySQL (comma separated longs)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I currently have a stored procedure that accepts TEXT as input, and then tries to find the matching ids within the set.

The input_ids value is an array of longs '1,2,3,...'.

It works but the problem is that find_in_set is slow, and I think there must be a better way.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sel_network_edges_by_id`(
    IN input_ids TEXT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT id, gradient, geoJson, ... 
    FROM network.network_edges 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, input_ids);
END
```

**Table Sample**

```
id, gradient, geoJson
1, -50, [34.34....]    
2, 110, [35.3345..]
3, 110, [35.3345..]
```

MySQL v8.0 (Azure)

Comment: Please provide a couple of sample lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `FIND_IN_SET` can't use an index you should use a prepared statement with `IN()`, where the values of the passed string can be used as an array inside `IN()` by concatenation.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sel_network_edges_by_id(IN input_ids TEXT)
BEGIN
  PREPARE my FROM CONCAT("SELECT id, gradient, geoJson, ... 
    FROM network.network_edges 
    WHERE id IN (,", input_ids,")");
  EXECUTE my;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE my;
END
```

Comment: Wouldn't be EXECUTE IMMEDIATE a leaner solution?

Comment: I had to put the CONCAT into a separate SET, but it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Afaik EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is only supported by MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a temporary table and join it with the main table with this process:

1. **Parsing Input String:**
   Convert the comma-separated input string into a temporary table that holds the IDs as separate rows. This can be done using a string splitting function:

   ```sql
   CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STRING(x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
   RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
              LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
              delim, '');
   ```

   Now you can use this function to split the input_ids and insert them into a temporary table:

   ```sql
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_ids (id INT);

   DECLARE pos INT DEFAULT 1;
   DECLARE sub_id VARCHAR(255);

   WHILE pos <= LENGTH(input_ids) - LENGTH(REPLACE(input_ids, ',', '')) + 1 DO
       SET sub_id = SPLIT_STRING(input_ids, ',', pos);
       INSERT INTO temp_ids (id) VALUES (CAST(sub_id AS INT));
       SET pos = pos + 1;
   END WHILE;
   ```
2. **Query Using Join:**
   Once you have the IDs in the temporary table, you can perform a more efficient query using a join:

   ```sql
   SELECT ne.id, ne.gradient, ne.geoJson, ...
   FROM network.network_edges ne
   JOIN temp_ids ti ON ne.id = ti.id;
   ```

Although this solution is more efficient than `FIND_IN_SET`, it does involve more steps. However, it should perform better, especially for larger datasets, as it avoids string manipulations and allows for optimized indexing. Temporary tables have session scope, so they will be automatically dropped when the session ends.

Comment: Far too cumbersome, difficult to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can consider using the `IN` operator instead of `FIND_IN_SET`, because this approach should provide better performance compared to using `FIND_IN_SET`! you can also convert the `input_ids` string into a JSON array using JSON_ARRAY, then use the `JSON_CONTAINS` function to check if each id is present in the `input_ids` array, because with `JSON_CONTAINS`, you can improve the performance of your stored procedure compared to using `FIND_IN_SET`!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sel_network_edges_by_id`(
    IN input_ids TEXT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT id, gradient, geoJson, ... 
    FROM network.network_edges 
    WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_ARRAY(input_ids), CAST(id AS JSON));
END
```